# How to submit a form with "Enter" in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, form-submit, enter

I have a search form without a submit button. How can I route to `#!/result`, by pressing the enter key?

HTML:

```
<form ng-controller="searchCtrl">
   <input ng-href='#!/result' type="text"  placeholder="Поиск">
</form>
```

JS:

```
App.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/result',{
                templateUrl:'../views/result.html',
                controller:"searchCtrl",})  
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To submit a form with <kbd>ENTER</kbd> you need a submit button. If you don't want one, a tricky way would be adding an invisible button in the form:

```
<form ng-submit="redirect()">
    ...
    <input type="submit" style="visibility: hidden"/>
</form>
```

Note that I added a ng-submit call in the form:

```
$scope.redirect = function() {
    $location.href('/result');
}
```

## [Here is a Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/hr1SNZQqcqgitNkPt2sS?p=preview)

Comment: Me can not use `<input type="submit">` because when user press `enter` submit automatically activated.